# Javascript: random sprite selection in constructor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making my first game in canvas/JS and I'm running into an issue with function constructors. We're trying to make it so that the Enemy object randomly takes one of two sprites on creation. Here's a snippet of our code:

```
function Enemy() {
    // Boilerplate stuff omitted. Relevant bit:

    if (randomFromTo(1,50)%2 === 0) { // Assume this function works correctly
        this.sprite.src = "images/scientist_1.png";
    } else {
        this.sprite.src = "images/scientist_2.png";
    }
}

var enemy1 = new Enemy();
var enemy2 = new Enemy(); // etc
```

It seems straightforward enough, but it ends up with every enemy object having the same sprite. I have no idea why this would happen - if I put console log message in the appropriate places, it logs the correct choices, but every enemy ends up with the same sprite anyways. So what's the best way to go about this, assuming it's possible? Thanks!

Comment: How do you initialize `this.sprite`? Maybe all enemies share the same Image object?

Comment: What is `this.sprite`? Where is it declared?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. We have a generic GameObject function that Enemy inherits from. Full code is [here.](http://pastebin.com/xEs8hzRW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this.sprite is outside of Enemy object you are probably overwritting it each time. The value you get is then the last one.

After viewing your code: Values in the prototype are shared by all instances. You should put instance related state in the instance (function) itself.

In this case put

```
    // Sprite
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = "";
```

in Enemy() {...}

Comment: It is; I pasted [more complete source](http://pastebin.com/xEs8hzRW) in a comment above. That seems like the most likely cause - any idea what we can do to work around it?

Comment: Why you don't put the sprite directly in Enemy ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are initializing `this.sprite` directly on the prototype, then all enemy objects share the same Image so each call to the constructor overwrites the image source of **all** enemies. So this does **not** work:

```
function Enemy()
{
    this.sprite.src = ...someRandomizedUrl...
}

Enemy.prototype.sprite = new Image();
```

You have to do it like this:

```
function Enemy()
{
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = ...someRandomizedUrl...
}
```

Your full source code is quite the same as the first code block (The wrong one) because all enemies share the same `GameObject` and therefor they share the same sprite image. Initialize `this.sprite` in the constructor of `Enemy` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Who likes cats?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrPv8/1/